# Is there any way I can display all post from facebook and not only mine?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm working on an app in which I intend to display the existing posts from my Facebook wall but in another design. I succeeded in getting my personal posts but for some reasons I cannot find the posts of the other users in my feed. Is there any way in which I can get all the post from my wall including my friends? Is this even possible? I could not find an answer yet, not even in the docs.

Thanks!

Comment: no, that is impossible since many years.

Comment: @luschn Thank you for your comment.